# Is there any way to know whether the parent window is closed or not in django view?

Tags: javascript, python, django, httpresponse

I have a django view which is supposed to return `HttpResponse` depending on the status of the parent window which created the current window. If the parent window is still open, then I want to close the current window and redirect the parent window to some url, else if the parent window is closed then I want to redirect the new window to that url. Is there any way to determine this in my django view?

I tried this in Javascript

```
if (!window.opener.parent.closed){
    window.close();
    window.opener.parent.location.href="<url>";
}
else{
    window.location.href="<url>";
}
```

But the `else` block is not executed even if the parent window is closed, the `if` block works fine if the parent indow is open.

Comment: Are you opposed to doing this in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with a window that popped up a new window, you should be checking for `window.opener`.

I would try the following code:

```
if(window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
  window.opener.location.href="<url>"
  window.close()

}
```

You can put the else in a timeout, as the parent window can be closed at any time without the child knowing.

```
var intervalID;

function checkParent() {
    if (window.opener && window.opener.closed) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        window.opener.location.href="<url>"
    }
}
var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkParent, 500);
```